# Disable Flat Rate for Downloadable Products

Tags: magento-1.9, products, downloadable

Our store has a fixed handling rate of 5ZAR for any product. Obviously, this is not needed for downloadable products. Where can I disable the flat rate, as set up under `System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Modules`, for downloadable products?

I have now searched EVERYWHERE and can not find an answer.

Comment: can you please tell your curretn cart have a simple and a dowload product then what  will the happen

Comment: The fixed handling rate remains at 5ZAR.

Comment: that means when cart only have download  product that time 5ZAR will be remove?

Comment: Yes, when the cart only has a downloadable product, 5ZAR should not be applied.

Comment: can please show the model class code of shipping module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as magento system  `collectRates()` function of a shipping module model class  has been `responsible` for `shipping activation and deactivation at checkout.`

I guss that You shipping class is `YourCompany_NewModule_Model_Carrier_ShippingMethod`  of your module then

On `collectRates()`,you can check `current quote/cart  have  only downloable` product then `basic of logic  inactive the method`

```
  public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        .........


        $hasOnlyDownloadproduct = 0;
        $noofdonloadPro=0;
        $toltalItem=0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $toltalItem++;
                if($item->getProductTypeId()=='downloadable'):
                $noofdonloadPro++;
                $hasOnlyDownloadproduct=1;
                else:
                $hasOnlyDownloadproduct=0;
                endif;
            }
        }
        // reomve the Shippin method
        if($toltalItem>0 && $noofdonloadPro>0):
            // If totaly item at cart and  no of download has same then disable the shipping methoo;
            if($toltalItem==$noofdonloadPro):
                 return false;
            endif;
        endif;
    .....

       return $result;
    }
```